# javascript How to make an odometer to start counting onload?

Tags: javascript

How to make an odometer to start counting onload https://jsfiddle.net/aht87opr/6/ ? (I've tried but to no avail, the snipet which should start it is at the bottom of javascript). I am javascript beginner please help :)

This is Gavin Brock's Odometer http://brock-family.org/gavin/software/web/odometer.html

```
    //<![CDATA[
        var n = 0;
        var myOdometer;
        function startcounting () {
            var div = document.getElementById("odometerDiv");
            myOdometer = new Odometer(div, {value: n, digits: 6, tenths: true});
            update();
        }

        function update () {
            n=n+0.0025
            myOdometer.set(n);
            setTimeout("update()", 0);
        }
    //]]>

startcounting();
```

Answer (score 2):

it does not work because setTimeout wants you to pass a function handle (you pass a string)

try `setTimeout(update, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Passing_string_literals):

> A string passed to setTimeout is evaluated in the global context, so local symbols in the context where setTimeout() was called will not be available when the string is evaluated as code.

Additionally,

> This syntax is **not recommended** for the same reasons that make using eval() a security risk.

Your code isn't working because `setTimeout`, when passed code as a string, can't see your `update` method. You can both fix this and improve the quality of your code by just passing `update` directly, as @dolek recommends